# Template not found in /admin in django

Tags: django

when i give the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ it is automatically redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ and showing the error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/

admin/login.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version:     2.0.6
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

admin/login.html

Exception Location:     /media/nimish/WINDOWS/Users/Home/engineerbabu/user_interface/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in select_template, line 47
Python Executable:  /media/nimish/WINDOWS/Users/Home/engineerbabu/user_interface/mysite/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.5.2
Python Path:    

['/media/nimish/WINDOWS/Users/Home/engineerbabu/user_interface/mysite',
 '/media/nimish/WINDOWS/Users/Home/engineerbabu/user_interface/mysite/venv/lib/python35.zip',
 '/media/nimish/WINDOWS/Users/Home/engineerbabu/user_interface/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5',
 '/media/nimish/WINDOWS/Users/Home/engineerbabu/user_interface/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/media/nimish/WINDOWS/Users/Home/engineerbabu/user_interface/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/media/nimish/WINDOWS/Users/Home/engineerbabu/user_interface/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 6 Jun 2018 12:15:54 +0000
```

My template settings are :-

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
```

Comment: Have you done any customizations to your admin views? What are your settings for `TEMPLATES`?

Comment: @Ralf no, i haven't applied any customizations in the admin views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have 'django.contrib.admin' in settings.py installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `'OPTIONS'` at the very beginning of your list `TEMPLATES` :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ]
    }
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
```

It looks like you haven't print your whole list in your example, so keep it and just move the `'OPTIONS'` to the top.

Comment: It is not a `list` but a `dict`. How will putting to the top help?